# Possible to use the new template context syntax in @Input: TemplateRef?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to utilize the [new template syntax](https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet#description) to pass a template with parameters to a custom component.

I tried to implement it here, but it doesn't work.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mpohjp

**hello.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `
    <h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template"></ng-container>
  `,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() name: string;

  @Input() template: TemplateRef<any>;
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<hello name="{{ name }}" [template]="test; context: { $implicit: 'success' }"></hello>

<ng-template #test let-myVar>
  Testing {{ myVar }}
</ng-template>
```

If we look at the [TemplateRef](https://angular.io/api/core/TemplateRef) class, the [createembeddedview](https://angular.io/api/core/TemplateRef#createembeddedview) takes a context argument. Which must mean that the created template that is passed to the component must already have the context. So I'm thinking it should be possible some how.

It might be the case that the `template; context` syntax sugar only works on `*ngTemplateOutlet`. If that's the case, then how do I pass a `TemplateRef` with the context inside it to a custom component and `*ngTemplateOutlet`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the template is the input, so you can pass object or string or something like that but not expression `test; context: { $implicit: 'success' }`

**So first change this :**

```
[template]="test; context: { $implicit: 'success' }"
```

**To :**

```
[template]="{ template : test , context: { $implicit : 'success' } }"
```

---

**And Second change, this :**

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template"></ng-container>
```

**To :**

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template.template; context: template.context"></ng-container>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-component-template-ref)**

Comment: That's pretty sweet. But I was hoping the `HelloComponent` wouldn't have to change.